# how to tie powerpoint bullet to related image for purposes of animation?

Tags: powerpoint

I'm building a set of slides with bullets.  I want to use "appearance" animations so I can step through the bullets with the space bar.  On several slides, I have a screenshot image that I've positioned right after the bullet I want the image to be associated with. However, when I add appearance animations, the slide just displays all the screenshot images immediately, before any of the bullets appear.  It seems like PowerPoint treats the images as "floating", and not associated with the bullets.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the screenshot image is near the bullet doesn't make it part of the bullet or associated text, so it's behaving as expected.

Instead, try using a custom picture bullet for the text or using individual lines of text, each grouped with the screenshot image and each animated individually.

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea what you mean by either of these strategies.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in code?  If not, SuperUser would be a more appropriate place to ask the question. In any case, you can't do what you want to do without a few tricks.

Comment: Ok.  I'll try posting this there.  I've already posted the same question in several places, and this is the only place I've gotten any reply at all, so I suppose one more won't hurt.